# Why do I have a compiler error (CS1503) in this Ozeki file?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, axis, onvif, ozeki

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;

using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;

using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Ozeki.Camera;
using Ozeki.Media;
using Ozeki;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace BasicCameraViewer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private VideoViewerWPF _videoViewerWPF;
        private BitmapSourceProvider _provider;
        private IIPCamera _ipCamera;
        private WebCamera _webCamera;
        private MediaConnector _connector;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _connector = new MediaConnector();
            _provider = new BitmapSourceProvider();

            SetVideoViewer();

        }
        private void SetVideoViewer()
        {
            _videoViewerWPF = new VideoViewerWPF
            {
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
                Background= Brushes.Black

             };
            CameraBox.Children.Add(_videoViewerWPF);

            _videoViewerWPF.SetImageProvider(_provider);
        }

        #region IP Camera Connect/Disconnect

        private void ConnectIPCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var host = HostTextBox.Text;
            var user = userTextBox.Text;
            var pass = Password.Password;

            _ipCamera = IPCameraFactory.GetCamera(host, user, pass);
            if (_ipCamera == null) return;
            _connector.Connect(_ipCamera.VideoChannel, _provider);

            _ipCamera.Start();
            _videoViewerWPF.Start();

        }

        private void DiconnectIPCamera_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _videoViewerWPF.Stop();

            _ipCamera.Disconnect();
            _ipCamera.Dispose();

            _connector.Disconnect(_ipCamera.VideoChannel, _provider);
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Can somebody tell me what I could do? It tells me that i can not convert the _videoViewerWPF.SetImageProvider(_provider) line from Ozeki.Media.BitmapSourceProvider to Ozeki.Media.IImageProvider and i have absolutely no idea what to do that it could work.

I tried several times to do something, but I dont even know what I´m doing.
I would be thankfull if somebody could help me so I can finish this.

Comment: `_videoViewerWPF.SetImageProvider` expects a parameter of type `IImageProvider<Image>` but `BitmapSourceProvider` does not implement `IImageProvider<Image>`. It implements `IImageProvider<BitmapSource>`. That's why you are getting error.

Comment: and how can I fix this? Im sorry, Im not that into programming yet :/

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue after following the Ozeki video [C# camera tutorial #3 - Camera viewer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sN2W8IkhIaM) on YouTube.

It may be that the API has moved on since that video because sample code on the Ozeki Website ([How to connect to an RTSP camera and display the picture in C#](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_36-how-to-connect-to-an-rtsp-camera-and-display-the-picture-in-c-using-wpf.html)) uses a DrawingImageProvider instead of a BitmapSourceProvider:

```
...

private DrawingImageProvider _provider = new DrawingImageProvider();

...
```

...and then (for a WPF app):

```
_videoViewerWpf.SetImageProvider(_provider);
```

In my case, this fixed the compiler error and I can now display RTSP video in a WPF app.